# xpath - IndexError: list index out of range after selecting element with path

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, index-error

I get the following Index error when trying to run the code below (found here: https://github.com/israel-dryer/Twitter-Scraper/blob/main/twitter-scraper-tut.ipynb):

*card = cards[0]

IndexError: list index out of range*

Since I am a Python newbie could you help me figure this out please?
Thanks a lot!!!

```
card = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="tweet"]')
card = cards[0]

#function that collects tweets while scrolling; filters out sponsored tweets; saves tweets in Tuple
def get_tweet_data(card):
    # get username of the tweet
    username_tweet = card.find_element_by_xpath('.//span').text
    # get Twitter Handle
    handle_tweet = card.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[contains(text()."@")]').text

    # get date of post - if no date, then sponsored tweet - then do not return
    try:
        date_tweet = card.find_element_by_xpath('.//time').get_attribute('datetime')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return
    # get Text of Tweet
    comment = card.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[2]/div[2]/div[1]').text
    responding = card.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[2]/div[2]/div[2]').text
    text_tweet = comment + responding
    # number of replies, retweets, likes
    reply_count = card.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@data-testid="reply"]').text
    retweet_count = card.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@data-testid="retweet"]').text
    like_count = card.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@data-testid="like"]').text

    tweet = (username_tweet, handle_tweet, date_tweet, text_tweet, reply_count, retweet_count, like_count)
    return tweet

get_tweet_data(card)
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="tweet"]')` did not return anything, i.e. there are no elements that match that xpath

Answer (score 0):

find_elements_by_xpath() returns a list of found elements or None if no elements are found. So in this case you need check length of 'card' before getting items from it. E.g.:

```
cards = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="tweet"]')
if len(cards) > 0:
    card = cards[0]
else:
    raise NoSuchElementException('No cards were found')
```

Maybe, it would be better if you will use `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` instead of `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()` - it will return an exception if no elements are found.